# Did my dentist lie to me?

Tags: dentistry

I went to the dentist a couple of years ago for a diagnosis of my jaw clicking. He told me it was TMJ joint disorder and said that my jaw was misalligned and needed to be corrected. he showed me a mirror and showed how the two teeth on the top were fractionally misalligned with the gap of the bottom two teeth.

now he told me to lift my arm. I did, and he was easily able to push my arm down. He told me my misaligned jaw meant that my muscles were off centre and therefore weak. He then moved my jaw until the top and bottom teeth were centered and made me bite onto a popsicle stick. Now he told me to put my arm out and when he tried to push it down he said he couldn't because i am much stronger now. He prescribed me a $2000 AUD pair of braces that i can put on and off, which will fix my TMJ. He said it could take a few months, he said it could take a few years, but it will eventually be cured. Back then i was still a kid living with my mum and I told her the TMJ joint disorder made my jaws lock when i opened my mouth and i couldn't eat so she ended up buying it for me. I wore it for about a week and it just felt like it was making things worse. so i stopped wearing it and after about 3 days it got better. 3 months after that i went to the dentist again who said i got much better. I didn't tell him that i stopped wearing it.

The reason im bringing this up is because i saw the "put your arm out and resist me pushing your arm down" thing done by this energy stone seller on TV. It seemed like a con artist gig. Also, my tmj has been acting up again 3 days ago. do misalligned jaws really weaken you by so much? are jaw correction braces the best way to fix TMJ?

Comment: IANAD, TMJ Disorder is a legitimate thing that creates Myofascial pain: https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?ContentTypeID=85&ContentID=P00899 but if you question his diagnoses go to another independent dentist.

Comment: Get option from a second dentist

Answer (score 1):

That 'put your arm out' scenario is a kinesiology practice.  You can google it to find out more.  I have known people who say it's very accurate and others who say it's hocus-pocus.

Maybe it's similar to homeopathy that seems to work on some people but not on others.